# Can events be simplified like this?

Tags: probability

Is it true that given three events $A, B$ and $C$, we can write $C = (C\cap B) \cup (C\cap B')$? Follow up: If so, can we then write $P(C) = P(C\cap B) + P(C \cap B')$?

Also, if $A, B$ and $C$ were exhaustive with $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive, and $A$ and $C$ independent, is it true that $P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap C')$?

Comment: The first claim is just the usual [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). For the second,  If $A,B$ are mutually exclusive then $P(A\cap B)=0$, but $P(A\cap C')$ need not be $0$.

Comment: @lulu Ok. Given the conditions in the second claim, can we write $P(C) = P(C \cap B) + P(C\cap B')$?

Comment: As I said, that's just the usual Law of Total Probability.  You don't need to make any assumptions about $C$ or $B$.

Comment: I see. Thank you! @lulu